# Import specific by month data from a large database

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language, google-workspace

I have a large database (almost 450,000 cells from A to AC columns and 15,000 rows), so I need that instead of importing all the data I just need that data from an specific month or weeknums.

Right now I'm doing it manually but it takes a lot of mi time to manually change the ranges of my IMPORTRANGE. I have a formula like:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10oV2kyv3aclctdydhZwxG3Y8VLdfkAr28aLz5fVZL1o","Form Responses 1!A2:AC"),"Select * Where year(Col1)=2017 and month(Col1)=1")
```

But it tells me that the result is too long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using one open-ended range use several import range and arrays, something like:

```
=QUERY(
{
IMPORTRANGE("10oV2kyv3aclctdydhZwxG3Y8VLdfkAr28aLz5fVZL1o","Form Responses 1!A2:AC5001");
IMPORTRANGE("10oV2kyv3aclctdydhZwxG3Y8VLdfkAr28aLz5fVZL1o","Form Responses 1!A5002:AC10001");
IMPORTRANGE("10oV2kyv3aclctdydhZwxG3Y8VLdfkAr28aLz5fVZL1o","Form Responses 1!A210002:AC15001")
},
"Select * Where year(Col1)=2017 and month(Col1)=1"
)
```